# How to add inline comment in quill.js editor?

Tags: quill

I have to create online word editor which include basic formatting, inline comments. For this i am using quill.js editor but i am unable to add comments in quill.js editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case i have created a custom solution for this. Below is a code pen link.

[`Quill.js comment functionality`](https://codepen.io/sainttushar/pen/yKLdOe)

Open this link and select text for which you want to comment and then click on Comment button shown in red font.